# How can I detach the door of my embedded mail box?

Tags: repair

I am the proud owner of an 80 year old 4 unit building in Los Angeles. One of the units has a mail box that is embedded in the wall.  The mailbox can be accessed from a door or grille on the inside wall of the living room room. The “door” is hinged and I want to remove the door so I can clean off the paint.  I cannot figure out how to detach the hinged door.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps pics looking at the internal sides would be more useful.

Comment: It'd be helpful to have a pic of the hinge point. Take the pic at an upward angle, with the lens facing either side's the hinge point. Get the objective (the frontmost lens face) as far into the opening as you can, so the pic will show as much detail as possible about how the hinge is constructed.

Comment: Also, make sure that the picture is actually clear and focused. If it's as fuzzy as this one, it probably won't be of much help. It may be necessary to turn the flash on the phone on to get enough light for the camera to focus accurately.

Comment: I have some pics of the hinge on the door/grill and will upload them as soon as I can figure out how to do this

Comment: I'm going to guess that the pivot pins were put into holes in the vertical sides before the frame was assembled or that they're screwed in from the outside of the frame. The first would require disassembling the entire mail box, then second would require at least taking it out of the wall. You may be stuck with putting down some plastic to catch drips & a mess and stripping it in place.

Comment: the top picture shows something that may be a hinge pin

Answer (score 1):

The grill or gate (?) is pinned into a metal frame. You can remove the grill from the frame. I have done it but I had the whole frame with the grill attached off the wall.

Trying to do it mounted into the wall would be hard without breaking the pins. The pins are stuck inside a hole then bent backwards back over the grill. Even when I used needle nose pliers to bend back and straighten the pins it was difficult they did not want to come back out of the hole. It was like when they put the pins in they than smashed and purposely misshaped them so they wouldn't fit to come back out.

I would not suggest doing it while in the wall unless you first see how it is constructed beforehand. Even then If you want to keep the integrity of the door/grill I wouldn't advise it. But I am not the most skilled in these things so who knows maybe someone else can do it easy peasy.

I have removed the frame from the wall before which you could do if you wanted to clean the grill then dry wall it back up. If you're good at patching and drywall, not that big of a deal. If not you might want to just get a heat gun and strip the paint off or use a paint remover. Not sure what your grill is made of so not sure exactly what to advise but personally I would first try acetone or denatured alcohol then maybe the heat gun first if the paint is the only issue. Again not the most handy so I hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: "Does anyone know where to buy a replacement grill?" is a shopping question and not typically allowed/tolerated. Removed as I think the rest of the answer is pretty good.